# Micronaut 4: Use expression language to set QueryValue default value fails

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm trying to use Micronaut's 4 expression language to set a default value for a query value, when its missing. In the listing below I use the expression `#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}` to create an instance of the current `LocalDate` as a fallback value

```java
@Controller("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Get
    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
    @ReadOnly
    public ModelAndView<Map<String, Object>> index(@QueryValue(value = "cutOffDate", defaultValue = "#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now()}") LocalDate cutOffDate) {

        if (LocalDate.now().isBefore(cutOffDate)) {
            cutOffDate = LocalDate.now();
        }

        return new ModelAndView<>("index", Map.of("cutOffDate", cutOffDate));
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but if I run the application I get the following error.

```bash
30.01.2024 20:43:35.542 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor]

Message: io/wangler/solaria/controller/$HomeController$Expr0
Path Taken: DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory.buildDefaultServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration configuration) --> new DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext,[RouteExecutor routeExecutor],MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,MessageBodyHandlerRegistry messageBodyHandlerRegistry,StaticResourceResolver staticResourceResolver,ThreadFactory nettyThreadFactory,HttpCompressionStrategy httpCompressionStrategy,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory,EventLoopGroupRegistry eventLoopGroupRegistry,WebSocketUpgradeHandlerFactory webSocketUpgradeHandlerFactory) --> new RouteExecutor([Router router],BeanContext beanContext,RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ErrorResponseProcessor errorResponseProcessor,ExecutorSelector executorSelector)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor]

Message: io/wangler/solaria/controller/$HomeController$Expr0
Path Taken: DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory.buildDefaultServer(NettyHttpServerConfiguration configuration) --> new DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext,[RouteExecutor routeExecutor],MediaTypeCodecRegistry mediaTypeCodecRegistry,MessageBodyHandlerRegistry messageBodyHandlerRegistry,StaticResourceResolver staticResourceResolver,ThreadFactory nettyThreadFactory,HttpCompressionStrategy httpCompressionStrategy,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory,EventLoopGroupRegistry eventLoopGroupRegistry,WebSocketUpgradeHandlerFactory webSocketUpgradeHandlerFactory) --> new RouteExecutor([Router router],BeanContext beanContext,RequestArgumentSatisfier requestArgumentSatisfier,HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration,ErrorResponseProcessor errorResponseProcessor,ExecutorSelector executorSelector)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2324)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2291)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2956)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2917)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.$RouteExecutor$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2309)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2291)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2956)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2917)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2309)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2291)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2956)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2917)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1711)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.$DefaultNettyEmbeddedServerFactory$BuildDefaultServer0$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2309)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2291)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2956)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2917)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2730)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1792)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1767)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:872)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:346)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:322)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:308)
    at io.wangler.Application.main(Application.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/wangler/solaria/controller/$HomeController$Expr0
    at io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Definition$Exec.$metadata$index(Unknown Source)
    at io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Definition$Exec.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Definition.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Definition$Intercepted$Definition.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Definition$Intercepted$Definition$Reference.load(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinitionReference.load(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinitionReference.java:178)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanContext.java:1563)
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:64)
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:44)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.triggerBeanCreatedEventListener(DefaultBeanContext.java:2362)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.postBeanCreated(DefaultBeanContext.java:2339)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2283)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2291)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3054)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2956)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2917)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2891)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3506)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3454)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3424)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:1451)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:95)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBeansOfType(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2253)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeansOfTypeForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1476)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.$DefaultRouter$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2309)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.wangler.solaria.controller.$HomeController$Expr0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 79 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am aware of the following restriction, mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#evaluatedExpressions).

> Expressions are currently not supported for "type use" annotations (that declare ElementType.TYPE_USE).

As far as I can tell `QueryValue` does not apply to that restriction.

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Bindable
@Inherited
public @interface QueryValue {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Bindable.class,
        member = "value"
    )
    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Bindable.class,
        member = "defaultValue"
    )
    String defaultValue() default "";
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I'm sure I am missing something…